# Given the feet of the altitudes of $\triangle ABC,$ point $R$ and the midpoint $P$ of $\overline{AB}$, prove$ |RA|\cdot|RB|=|RP|\cdot|RN|$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, power-of-the-point

> Let $K,M,N$ be feet of the altitudes of $\triangle ABC$ from the vertices $A,B,C$ respectively, $P$ be the midpoint of the edge $\overline{AB}$ and $R$ be the intersection point of the lines $AB$ and $KM$. Prove:
> $$|RA|\cdot|RB|=|RP|\cdot|RN|$$

---

**My attempt:**

**Edit:** In the meantime, I improved my proof a little bit.

Let $O$ be the orthocenter of $\triangle ABC$. Then $\triangle MKN$ is *orthic*.

Since $\measuredangle BMA=\measuredangle BKA=90^\circ$, $ABKM$ is a cyclic quadrilateral.

According to the *power of a point theorem*: $$|AR|\cdot|BR|=|MR|\cdot|RK|.$$

Feet $K,M,N$ of the altitudes and the midpoint $P$ are concyclic,i. e., $K,M,N, P$ belong to the *nine-points circle*, so we can apply the *power of a point theorem* once again:
$$\begin{aligned}&|RN|\cdot|RP|=|MR|\cdot|RK|\\\implies& |AR|\cdot|BR|=|RN|\cdot|RP|\end{aligned}$$

However, I don't remember we have mentioned the *nine-points circle* in our online lectures and I don't know how to prove $K,M,N,P$ are concyclic.

---

I tried to prove $\triangle NMR\sim\triangle KRP$, but I'm not sure if it really is so.

Quadrilaterals $ANOM, NBKO$ and $CMOK$ are cyclic.
$$\begin{aligned}|PB|=|PM|\implies\measuredangle PKM&=\measuredangle PBK\\\measuredangle OCM&=\measuredangle OKM=\measuredangle ABM\\\measuredangle KCO&=\measuredangle KMO=\measuredangle KAB\\\measuredangle APC&=2\measuredangle PBK\\\measuredangle PKA+\measuredangle BKP&=90^\circ\\\implies\measuredangle PKM&=\measuredangle PBK\end{aligned}$$

[image]

Just in case: $\color{red}{\triangle AKC\sim\triangle BCM},\color{purple}{\triangle BRM\sim\triangle KRA},\color{blue}{\triangle RBK\sim\triangle RAM}$ and $\color{green}{\triangle ABC\sim\triangle CMK}$.

Is there any way I could use those facts in this proof?

Thank you in advance!

---

**Update:**

Thanks to @Richrow in the comment section,

$$\color{red}{\measuredangle KNB}=\measuredangle KOB=\measuredangle AOM=\color{red}{\measuredangle ANM}$$

and then it follows, like @richrow said,
$$\measuredangle MPK=2\measuredangle MBK$$
And special thanks to @user21820!

Comment: I'm confused about your use of the power of a point theorem. It should be $|RA| \times |RB| = |RM| \times |RK| = |RN| \times |RP|$. You have there $|RM| \times |MK|$ instead.

Comment: @TodorMarkov, sorry, I see my missleading typo in the very beginning. Once I wrote it, I just copied it in the following part.

Comment: In order to prove that $K$, $M$, $N$ and $P$ are concylic you can just check the equality of $\angle MNK$ and $\angle MPK$ (they both are equal to $180^{\circ}-2\angle A$).

Comment: @richrow, thank you very much! At the end, I got lost in my own picture. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Compare $∠MPA$ and $∠MKN$ by using the property of angle at circle centre and the cyclic quadrilaterals in the orthocentric system that you already found.

Comment: I found this, $\color{red}{\measuredangle KNB}=\measuredangle KOB=\measuredangle AOM=\color{red}{\measuredangle ANM}$, but kind of got lost in my picture. Oh, I see! Thank you!